# nsdictionary is not in order in my tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsdictionary

i have this dictionary:

```
" a) 2012 UN NEWNW" =     (
    "2012/06/04 Saudi Arabia Huge Sandstorm",
    "2012/05/27 Niger Huge Sandstorm"
);
" b) 2012 DEUX " =     (
    "2011/03/30 Niger Huge Sandstorm"
);
" c) just for TROIS" =     (
    "2011/03/30 AHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 BHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 CHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 1Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 2Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 3Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 4Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 5CHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 6Huge Sandstorm over niger "
);
" d) ****** QUATRE" =     (
    "2011/03/30 7Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 8Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 9CHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 AHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 B10CHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "2011/03/30 **CHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    ""
);
```

and with this code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    // Configure the cell...

    //---------- CELL BACKGROUND IMAGE -----------------------------
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightGrey.png"];
    imageView.image = image;
    cell.backgroundView = imageView;
    [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    NSArray *allKeys = [states allKeys];
    NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *curArray = [states objectForKey:curKey];
    curValue = [curArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //Arrow 
    cell.textLabel.text = curValue;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    return cell;
}
```

the section order is c) b) a) d)
who can please help me?

Comment: a),b),c),d) are different - different array or the one time responce??

Comment: [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries don't have a predictable order.  You need to sort `allKeys` before selecting by section.

Answer (score 2):

From the [NSDictionary class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

allKeys
Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.

```
- (NSArray *)allKeys
```

Return Value
A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the dictionary has no entries.

Discussion
The order of the elements in the array is not defined.

So you will need to sort this array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its not the dictionary issue because it has no order its a NSArray issue, Please sort your array according to key name.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1.Creat array of dictionary and store this dictionary in it in order you want, and use the same array in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

2.Compare section and access dictionary key by providing dictionary key manually instead of providing indexPath.row.